# Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers in Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm coding a project using nuxt3 and typescript, but I'm getting an error in my project and I couldn't solve it no matter what I did. I will be grateful if you could help me. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) or something similar that have legacy code,
to fix it you should install ES6 version of package [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es)

Comment: Lodash is not available in package.json. Should I still do it?